# React form getting reset with every change in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am developing a simple crud form with **formik** in react for Learning purposes, this
[image]

Now in this form I am facing two issues

**Ist Issue**

As **Quantity** field should only input numbers so I added a onChange listener and updated state if only number are inputted, it works fine, but problem is it **reset's** the whole form

```
<Field
    className="form-control"
    type="text"
    name="quantity"
    onChange={this.onChangeCheckNumber}
>
</Field>

onChangeCheckNumber = (event) => {
    const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;

    // if value is not blank, then test the regex

    if (event.target.value === '' || re.test(event.target.value)) {
        this.setState({ quantity: event.target.value })
    }
}
```

I think this piece of code is culprit

```
this.setState({ quantity: event.target.value })
```

As I am setting state, so I think my whole form gets re rendered again,

How to achieve this functionality perfectly ?

**2nd Issue**

**Warehouse selection depends upon city selection**, so I added a onChange on city and called warehouse for selected cityId and I am receiving data, but city drop down gets blocked.

My state properties

```
state = {
        quantity: 0,
        price: "0",
        comments: '',
        itemType: {
            key: 0,
            value: 'Select'
        },
        cities: {
            key: 0,
            value: 'Select'
        },
        warehouses: {
            key: 0,
            value: 'Select'
        },
        sellers: {
            key: 0,
            value: 'Select'
        },
        warehouseOptions: null
    }
```

In componentDidMount, I am initializing the dropdown values

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.itemTypeObject();
        this.cityObject();
        this.sellerObj();
    }
```

Fetching data with axios from server and updating state

```
cityObject = () => {
        axios.get('/cities')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    cities: response.data
                });
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

Inside my **Formik form** tag my city and warehouse dropdowns

```
<div>
        <label>City</label>
        <div>
            <Field
                as="select"
                onChange={this.onCityDropdownSelected}
                name="city"
            >
                {this.createCity()}
            </Field>
        </div>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Warehouse</label>
    <div>
        <Field
            className="form-control"
            as="select"
            name="warehouse"
        >
            {this.state.warehouseOptions}
        </Field>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my **onCityDropdownSelected**

```
onCityDropdownSelected = (event) => {
        if (event.target.value !== "0") {
            this.warehouseObj(event.target.value);
        } else {
            this.setState({
                warehouseOptions: null
            })
        }
    }

warehouseObj = (cityId) => {
        axios.get(`/warehouses/cityId/${cityId}`)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    warehouses: response.data
                });
                this.createWarehouse();
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

After this I get updated values in warehouse drop down, but city drop down opens , but does not change on selection.

Comment: For the first issue, I think you need to set a field named `value` that equals to the state value so that data is synced between component and component state

Comment: I think I am always updating the state without maintaining it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your 1st issue you are changing the whole state by doing `this.setState({ quantity: event.target.value })` as it will change your state and clear out all other state values and final state will only contain quantity resulting reseting form state.

To solve that issue you have to de structure your old state and than just change the quantity like this:

```
this.setState{...state, quantity: event.target.value}
```

as for the `onCityDropdownSelected` same issue is occurring. Please do tell me if this answer helps solve your problem.

Comment: I tried this,

onChangeCheckNumber = (event) => {
        const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;

        // if value is not blank, then test the regex

        if (event.target.value === '' || re.test(event.target.value)) {
            this.setState({...this.state, quantity: event.target.value})
        }
    }

Still no luck, sorry

At both places